# Two-body problem and motion in a central field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, orbital-motion

If we consider motion of a body in a central (gravitational) field the equation of motion would be
$$-\frac{\gamma m_1 m_2}{r^2}\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=m_1 \vec{r}^{\prime\prime}$$
where the origin of inertial frame of reference is placed in the center of gravity.

For two-body problem (also with gravitational force between them) the equations of motion would be
$$-\frac{\gamma_1 m_1 M}{\rho_1^2}\frac{\vec{\rho_1}}{\rho_1}=m_1 \vec{\rho_1}^{\prime\prime}$$
$$-\frac{\gamma_2 m_2 M}{\rho_2^2}\frac{\vec{\rho_2}}{\rho_2}=m_2 \vec{\rho_2}^{\prime\prime}$$
where the origin of inertial frame of reference is placed in the center of mass, $\vec{\rho}_i$ points from center of mass to $m_i$, $M = m_1+m_2, \gamma_1 = \frac{\gamma m_2^3}{M^3}, \gamma_2 = \frac{\gamma m_1^3}{M^3}$

I am stuck with the following. If, for example, I consider two-body model and try to switch to a reference frame (which is moving uniformly) that is associated, for example, with the second object, then this reference frame will be non-inertial, meaning that the equations of motion in it will look as follows

$$-\frac{\gamma_1 m_1 M}{r_1^2}\frac{\vec{r_1}}{r_1} + \vec{F}=m_1 \vec{r_1}^{\prime\prime}$$
$$-\frac{\gamma_2 m_2 M}{r_2^2}\frac{\vec{r_1}}{r_1} + \vec{F}=0$$

where $\vec{r}_1(\equiv \vec{r})$ is radius-vector from $m_2$ to $m_1$ and $\vec{F}=-m_2\vec{\rho_2}^{\prime\prime}$. And it seems like the second equation should be true and the first equation should be identical to equation of motion in a central field. However, from my computations it follows that $$-\frac{\gamma m_1 m_2}{r^2}\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \neq -\frac{\gamma_1 m_1 M}{r^2}\frac{\vec{r}}{r} + \vec{F}.$$ Thus, the trajectory obtained in this model for $m_1$ does not coincide with the trajectory obtained in the model with a central field, correct? It seems that the reason for this discrepancy lies in the fact that different reference frames are considered inertial in these models, however, I am unable to provide a rigorous explanation for this discrepancy either physically or mathematically.

So my question is which of these two models is more "right" in a physical scence? Or they are equvivalent?

Comment: A central field is unphysical because it breaks Galilean relativity. We teach it because it is slightly easier to deal with than the "correctly" calculated case with two masses, a properly relative force law and motion of both masses in the center of mass coordinates. Is that what you are asking? So, yes, the observation that the central field problem is not identical to the real Kepler problem is correct.

Comment: @FlatterMann thanks for reply! yes, this is kind of what I was asking about, although I could not formulate my question properly. But what do you mean by saying that "A central field is unphysical because it breaks Galilean relativity"? Also, it seems like Kepler laws are formulated for central field. Are they incorrect then?

Comment: Look at the motion of a body in a central field: it changes direction and velocity, which means that the momentum changes. Since we are not assigning a momentum to the field itself, this violates momentum conservation. In a properly formulated problem the total momentum of the two masses stays the same and the center of mass is stationary. By simplifying the problem we are destroying Galilean relativity (the force depends on one absolute coordinate rather than the difference of two coordinates). Similar things happen in wall-bounce problems etc..

Comment: @FlatterMann I can see that, but why is it wrong for momentum to change? I mean, we have Newton's second law which exctly postulates that the change in momentum in  inertial frame of reference equals to external force and it is exactly the case we have with central field. Why it is unphysical?

Comment: Is it wrong for a physical model to be unphysical? No. If you can live with the consequences, then it's fine. Nobody will get upset that the software that models spacecraft dynamics in the solar system doesn't calculate the change of planetary orbits due to the spacecraft, for instance. We had a similar problem with the potential well problem in QM: somebody noticed that the solutions are not conserving momentum and couldn't make sense of it. These systems are simply a learning opportunity to pay attention to these "trivial" aspects of models.

Comment: Kepler orbits aren't really an approximation in the way that this comment thread seems to suggest (at least in my reading), because they can be applied to arbitrary binary systems if you just take the central mass to be the sum of the two masses. This comes from thinking about the equation of motion of the separation vector.

Comment: Regarding the question, what is $m$ and why is there a factor of $(m_2/m)^3$ in all of the force expressions?

Comment: @Sten $m=m_1+m_2 \equiv M$ just fixed that